# Format an array of strings with arguments

Tags: android, string-formatting

I'd like to format an array of strings just like [android used to format strings](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling):

Usually we do:

- strings.xml

  ```
  <string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>
  ```
- In some java code:

  ```
  Resources res = getResources();
  String text = String.format(res.getString(R.string.welcome_messages), username, mailCount);
  ```

I'm looking for something like:

- in some arbitrary xml:

  ```
      <string-array name="employee">
          <item>name: %1$s</item>
          <item>post: %2$s</item>
      </string-array>
  ```
- in some java code:

  ```
  Resources res = getResources();
  String[] employee = ArrayString.format(res.getStringArray(R.string.employee), name, post);
  ```

Is there an elegant way to do that?

EDIT:

The next pieces of code is a workaround and I'm posting it just to help @Sufian, who asked for it in a comment. It's not a real answer once my question is about format the string array's content and the bellow code is formatting each string separately.

In some misc.xml:

```
<string-array
    name="string_array">
    <item>1st position: %1$d</item>
    <item>2nd position: %1$d</item>
</string-array>
```

Then, in java code:

```
res = getResources();
String[] sa = res.getStringArray(R.array.string_array);
for (int i = 0; i < sa.length; i++ ) {
    text += String.format(sa[i], i);
}
```

Comment: So, how did you solve it? I have a similar issue.

Comment: It seems that there is no elegant way to perform such formatting. You will need to iterate in each string array element and format it as your needs.

Comment: Hmm. Any sample could which you could share? For now I'm just picking Strings by name using the following code snippet, and providing formatting arguments like with simple resource Strings. http://steven.bitsetters.com/2007/11/27/accessing-android-resources-by-name-at-runtime/

Comment: I edited the answer with a workaround. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
String text = String.format(res.getStringArray(R.array.myStringArray)[index], param1, param2);
```

Answer (score 0):

getQuantityString may solve your problem.

Look at quantity strings in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Here's the specific API doc: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getQuantityString(int,%20int,%20java.lang.Object...)

Comment: @Chuck_Norris quantity strings actually selects one kind of formatting in a set of many possibilities based in the amount such as zero, few, many... I need to use the entire array string and each array position may be a string formatted with arguments.